# Hice una consulta que tiene que ver con hacer sumas y multiplicaciones y me salta Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras para mi primer sitio; todo lo demás ya me sale, me agrega y todo, pero a la hora de hacer esa suma y multiplicación que son para que me dé un total me salen los siguentes errores:

> **Warning:** A non-numeric value encountered in **C:\xampp\htdocs\El grano\cliente\carritodecompras.php on** line **63**

> **Warning:** A non-numeric value encountered in **C:\xampp\htdocs\El grano\cliente\carritodecompras.php** on line **67**

Lo siguiente es mi archivo:

**carritodecompras.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include 'conectar.php';
   if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {
     
   }else {
      if (isset($_GET['id_producto'])) {
        $nombre="";
        $precio=0;
        $image="";
        $id_producto = $_REQUEST['id_producto'];
                 $re = $Conexion->prepare ("SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE Id_producto = '$id_producto'");
                $re->execute();
          $resultado = $re->fetchAll();
                 foreach ($resultado as $producto) {
                   $nombre=$producto['Descripcion'];
                   $precio=$producto['Precio'];
                   $image=$producto['Foto'];
            }
            $arreglo[]=array('Id_producto' => $_GET['id_producto'], 
              'Descripcion' => $nombre,
              'Precio' => $precio,
              'Foto' => $image,
              'cantidad' =>1);
            $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
      }
   }

?>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Detalles</title>
        //ESTO LO PUSE POR QUE ES UN ICONO DE BOSSTRAP
    <a href="carritodecompras.php" title="ver carrito"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart-check-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M.5 1a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h1.11l.401 1.607 1.498 7.985A.5.5 0 0 0 4 12h1a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h7a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .491-.408l1.5-8A.5.5 0 0 0 14.5 3H2.89l-.405-1.621A.5.5 0 0 0 2 1H.5zM6 14a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0zm-1.646-7.646-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-1.5-1.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L8 8.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708z"/>
</svg></a>

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center login-page">
                <div class="col-md-12 login-form">
                <center><p class="login-form-font-header"><span><h1>CARRITO DE COMPRAS</h1></span><p></center>

            <section>
            <?php
                $total=0;
                 if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
                       $datos=$_SESSION['carrito'];
                       
                       $total=0;
                       for($i=0;$i<count($datos);$i++){
            ?>
                <div class="producto">
                <center>
                  
                   <img src="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Foto']; ?>" width="180">
                  <span><?php echo $datos[$i]['Descripcion'];?></span>
                   <span>Precio: $<?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio'];?> MXN</span>
                   <span>Cantidad: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['cantidad'];?>"></span>
                   **AQUI ME MARCA EL PRIMER ERROR**
                   <span>Total: $<?php echo $datos[$i]['cantidad']*$datos[$i]['Precio'];?> MXN</span>
                </center>
                </div>
            <?php
 **AQUI ME MARCA EL SEGUNDO ERROR**
                $total=($datos[$i]['cantidad']*$datos[$i]['Precio'])+$total;

             }
                 }else{
                  echo '<center><h2>El carrito de compras esta vacio</h2></center>';
                 }
                 echo '<center><h2>Total: '.$total.'</h2></center>';
            ?>  
           <center><a href="bienvenido1.php">Ver productos</center></a>
            </section>
                    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar esta línea de la siguiente forma: `<span>Total: $<?php echo floatval($datos[$i]['cantidad'])*floatval($datos[$i]['Precio']);?> MXN</span>`. El error que te aparece quiere decir que estas intentando hacer una multiplicación en un tipo de dato que no es número. Lo más probable es que estes tratado de multiplicar `strings`

Comment: Hola si se quita el anuncio pero no me da el total, me aparece solo un 0 sabras porque? es decir por ejemplo si en precio tengo 20 y en cantidad 1 al multiplicarlos me deberia de dar 20 pero me da 0

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `$datos[$i]['cantidad']` y $datos[$i]['precio'] en el `span`?¿El valor es el esperado (1 y 20)?

Comment: Al parecer tus variables `$datos[$i]['cantidad']` y `$datos[$i]['Precio']` no son un número válido, te recomiendo testear estás variables en tiempo de ejecución con `echo` así puedes descartar si esa es la falla.

Comment: Si no has encontrado ya el problema, prueba a hacer esto: `$precio=(int)$producto['Precio'];`, porque cantidad parece numérico, pero puedes ponérselo también...

Answer (score 0):

El error se sebe a que estás intentando multiplicar algo que no es un número. Eso probablemente se deba a que **$datos[$i]['cantidad']** o $datos[$i]['precio'] no son valores numéricos.

Probablemente uno de ellos o los dos sean de tipo **String**. Por eso al forzar php a tomar los valores como **floatval** te sale 0. (Por experiencia propia) Asegúrate de que en los inputs de POST en los que introduces la cantidad o estableces el precio, no se guardan en formato **String**.

No puedo ver mas lejos con el código compartido, espero que mi respuesta te ayuda y al menos sepas por dónde empezar a buscar.